# Scheduling a live agent/web chat agent in Salesforce Web Chat

Tags: liveagent

We have configured web chat in salesforce. Currently, the end-users can chat with the agents only if the agent is available, and there is no option for them the schedule an appointment with the live agents.

I researched this and found that end users can chat only when the agent is live. There is no option to schedule an appointment with the agent.

> So I am thinking of giving end-user an option to schedule an
>   appointment if the agent is offline.
>
> But the problem here is how can I route the scheduled requests to a
>   specific agent based on skills?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this with Live Agent OOTB as technically speaking you would need to have a "button/routing" for a specific agent, which is not practical. However, here is an idea I would consider if you really have to do this.

1. You need a mechanism to make appointments (schedule chats) in Salesforce.
2. Having that mechanism in place, you could have a specific queue to handle those slots available, that way, you would ensure somebody would be able to talk to the customer at that specific time.
3. Based on that slot, you could generate a link to a page (with some parameters in the URL to identify the slot) that would make the button come online based on the schedule and the customer.

This was just a thought but the feature itself is not made for this.